# DebugElement, By.css, nativeElement and.querySelector in Angular 11

Tags: angular, angular-test

The code below is from the link below.
https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-basics#bycss

> The server-side renderer might not support the full HTML element API.
> If it doesn't support querySelector, the previous test could fail.
>
> The DebugElement offers query methods that work for all supported
> platforms.

```
  it('should find the <p> with fixture.debugElement.query(By.css)', () => {
    const bannerDe: DebugElement = fixture.debugElement;
    const paragraphDe = bannerDe.query(By.css('p'));
    const p: HTMLElement = paragraphDe.nativeElement;
    expect(p.textContent).toEqual('banner works!');
  });
```

**My questions:**

1 Can the use of `DebugElement.query(By.css('p'))` avoid exception on non-browser?

2 Will the test cases of `'should have <p> with "banner works!"'`, and `'should find the <p> with fixture.debugElement.nativeElement)'` below cause exception on non-browser?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-banner',
  template: `<p>banner works!</p>`,
  styles: []
})
export class BannerComponent { }


import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BannerComponent } from './banner-initial.component';


describe('BannerComponent (with beforeEach)', () => {
  let component: BannerComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<BannerComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({declarations: [BannerComponent]});
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BannerComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should contain "banner works!"', () => {
    const bannerElement: HTMLElement = fixture.nativeElement;
    expect(bannerElement.textContent).toContain('banner works!');
  });

  it('should have <p> with "banner works!"', () => {
    const bannerElement: HTMLElement = fixture.nativeElement;
    const p = bannerElement.querySelector('p');
    expect(p.textContent).toEqual('banner works!');
  });


  it('should find the <p> with fixture.debugElement.nativeElement)', () => {
    const bannerDe: DebugElement = fixture.debugElement;
    const bannerEl: HTMLElement = bannerDe.nativeElement;
    const p = bannerEl.querySelector('p');
    expect(p.textContent).toEqual('banner works!');
  });

  it('should find the <p> with fixture.debugElement.query(By.css)', () => {
    const bannerDe: DebugElement = fixture.debugElement;
    const paragraphDe = bannerDe.query(By.css('p'));
    const p: HTMLElement = paragraphDe.nativeElement;
    expect(p.textContent).toEqual('banner works!');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes both of your test cases would run on non-browser. To confirm you could run your test cases using `ChromeHeadless` browser. You can read more about headless chrome in here https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome#tldr.
To use headless chrome you need to change your `karma.conf.js` file with  `browsers: ['ChromeHeadless']`

Comment: so you mean all three cases can run on non-browser? If so, why does the artcile on my OP describe like those two test bases from my second questions throw error?